# How to convert a .BPMN2 file to a BPEL file?

Tags: ode, bpel, bpmn, bpmn.io, bpelxexec

I have generated .BPMN file using eclipse BPMN2 plugin. I want to convert this file .BPEL file. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Oracle BPA (Business Process Analysis Suite) for that:

1. Create BPMN project and import your BPMN diagram there
2. Create new group in your project and name it SOA, for example.
3. Import SOA profiles into this group (right click >> *SOA* >> *Import SOA profiles*)
4. Right click your process and select *SOA* >> *Transform business process into BPEL process*
5. Click *Yes* to validate the process, and press *Finish*.

To view converted BPEL right click the process and choose *Go to BPEL process*.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion ..But I am looking for some pragmatically way to solve this ,like any java web service or any other stuff. I want to use  this it in my web service.